# Chrome extension that keeps running after window is deactivated(minimized)

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I am trying to make some simple Chrome extension that continuously reloads each tab opened in current window.

Currently my extension runs only when a window is active.

How can I get it running even after the window is deactivated(minimized)?

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,

  "name": "some name",
  "description": "some description",
  "version": "1.0",

  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "default.html",
    "default_title": "click here!"
  },
  "permissions": [
    "activeTab",
    "tabs",
    "cookies",
    "http://*.xxx.com/",
    "https://*.xxx.com/"
  ]
}
```

Here is manifest.json I am using. 
I am assuming that whether an extension can run in background has nothing to do with the extension script itself.
Am I right?

Comment: Why would you want this? What's the point of loading a screen people can't see. As soon as they see it the window will become active again. Just load it then.

Comment: Thank you for your advice, but that is what I want to do.

Comment: Do you have a solution after 3 years? :D. Currently, I work on the an extension same as your app, and stuck with it.

Answer (score 0):

The only piece of code your extension contains is a popup page (presumably, with scripts inside).

**A popup page is only loaded while it's shown.** As soon as the popup closes, the "tab" holding the page is torn down, and your code no longer executes.

For something that has to run at any time in the background there are, well, **background pages**. Their "tab" exists independently of the UI.

See documentation:

- [Architecture overview](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch)
- [Background pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/background_pages)
- [Event pages](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages) (more efficient in some scenarios, but harder to use)